# Paypal orders doesn't show up in panel

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm integrating a website with Paypal Express Checkout.

Everything was fine in sandbox mode, but when I put into production things don't go so well.

I'm able to send the user to the checkout page, pay the order and get the user back to my website (with a token and PayerID set in the query string of the redirect uri).

The problem is after that, the order disappear! I can't see it in the paypal panel history and I also don't receive any IPN about the current status of the order.

In sandbox everything was working fine.

Any ideias? I'm using CakePHP/PHP.

Comment: Are you confirming the order after the first return through express check out?

Comment: What you mean by "confirm"?

Comment: It's a two step process, first you get permission to make a charge, then you confirm the charge afterwards. Eg. Customer checks out, is transfered to paypal to confirm payment details, returns to your page and "confirms" the order

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the response and sorry for the huge delay for my feedback. So, do you have any links (preferably in PHP) that I can see about that last step?